# Get gradle runtime configuration from Java file

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have created a custom gradle plugin, where I need to make my task depends on this task. Since I can't do it from build.gradle, I was planning to do it in Java file. How do I convert it into a Java method? How do I get `configurations.runtime` from Java?

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "$projectDir/libs"
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile gradleApi()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you adding this task as well through your plugin?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. But I'm not able to get `configuration.runtime` in my java class. My plugin class is written in Java

Comment: configuration.runtime is added by the java plugin. Unless if you add that plugin to the project yourself, you wont be able to use it. You can add a task listener though.

Comment: I'va added Java plugin in my plugin's build.gradle

Comment: That's not the same as adding the java plugin to any project that uses your plugin.

Comment: Added build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively in your plugin, trying to add a `dependsOn` for a task that does not exist yet, task `copyLibs` does not exist at the time of applying your plugin. It is added to the task graph later as gradle parses the rest of build.gradle.

If the task copyLibs is standard, you can move it to your plugin implementation, so your plugin is then aware of copyLibs.

I'm not sure this would work, will have to test it out, but you could probably also add a listener to project.tasks (via your plugin) so that whenever a task called `copyLibs` is added to the project, you can register your dependency.

```
project.tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
  if (task.name == 'copyLibs') {
    MyTask.dependsOn(task)
  }
}
```